# Does pytest plugins work with python2.6

Tags: python, pytest, python-2.6

I am new to pytest and I have python2.6 installed on my setup.
I installed pytest and the testcases get executed properly. I installed couple of plugins like pytest-timeout, putest-xdist etc but these plugins does not load when I run the cases. For timeout, I get following error: 
 `py.test: error: unrecognized arguments: --timeout`
Same steps followed with python2.7 works. 
Any idea how this can be solved or alteast steps to debug to know what exactly is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately pytest < 3.0 "hides" the `ImportError` happening when failing to import a plugin. If you remove all plugin arguments but add `-rw`, you should be able to see what exactly is going wrong in the warning summary.

Comment: Even after adding `-rw`, no warning is displayed and the testcase gets executed successfully without plugin

Comment: That's odd - and `--version` doesn't list the plugin? Are you sure it's actually installed for that Python version?

Comment: Following is the output of *py.test --version*
This is pytest version 2.9.2, imported from /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pytest.pyc`

Comment: Yes the plugin is installed for Python-2.6

Comment: You only showed the first line, without answering the question if it's shown in that list. Also, does `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pytest_timeout.py` exist?

Comment: That is the only output I get on executing the `version` command. And yes the file exists

Answer (score 0):

In your conftest.py file just add the following line after the imports:

```
pytest_plugins = 'pytest_timeout'
```

It should solve your issue.